# Infer return type based on variadic argument type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm building a large CLI app with lots of commands and options, some of which are reused among commands. I'm using the [`yargs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) library and I find myself creating helper functions like the following:

```
const withFoo = (yargs: Argv) =>
    yargs.option('foo', {
        type: 'string',
    });

const withBar = (yargs: Argv) =>
    yargs.option('bar', {
        type: 'string',
    });
```

and them using them like this:

```
const bazOptionsBuilder = (yargs: Argv) =>
    withFoo(withBar(yargs)).option('baz', { type: 'string' });
```

Now, I wanted to create a helper function to reduce nesting, that I could do this instead:

```
const bazOptionsBuilder = withOptions(
    withFoo,
    withBar,
    /* ... possibly more here */
    (yargs) => yargs.option('baz', { type: 'string' }),
);
```

It's relatively trivial to implement the `withOptions` function, but I'm struggling with typing it. So far, I've come up with:

```
import { Argv } from 'yargs';
type YargsBuilder<A extends Argv> = (y: Argv) => A;
type ArgsOf<T> = T extends Argv<infer A> ? A : never;

export function withOptions<A extends Argv<any>, B extends Argv<any>>(
    a: YargsBuilder<A>,
    b: YargsBuilder<B>,
): YargsBuilder<Argv<ArgsOf<A> & ArgsOf<B>>>;
export function withOptions<A extends Argv<any>, B extends Argv<any>, C extends Argv<any>>(
    a: YargsBuilder<A>,
    b: YargsBuilder<B>,
    c: YargsBuilder<C>,
): YargsBuilder<Argv<ArgsOf<A> & ArgsOf<B> & ArgsOf<C>>>;
// ... and more ...
```

but this forces me to write typings for any number of arguments to `withOptions`. Is it possible to create a single type signature for `withOptions` that will say tell typescript for any number of passed in `YargsBuilder`s, the return type will be the union of all those types?

Comment: Is my understanding correct: you want `withOptions` to be a function that accepts a list of functions - that each take an `Argv` as input, mutate it and return it - and returns a function that given an `Argv` pipes it through each transformer function in turn?

Comment: If that is the case why do you need special typing at all?

Comment: Why not go with a configuration object approach instead of a builder?

Comment: @Aron, yes that is the case. It needs special typing because I want the resulting return type of the returned function to be the union type of the return values of all passed-in functions

Comment: @Lesiak the builder-pattern is coming from `yargs`, not from my code. I can't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible but not simple. You may want to consider structuring your code differently as others have suggested; I am not familiar with `yargs` so I can't comment on that.

This solution uses two one-off type aliases, you can just copy and paste them into their usage to remove them, or structure them differently depending on how you may want to type things within the function.

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEECcHMDdQDYHskGsDOp1ILYFMAXACwEsA7aRE1PUYk9AfgFgAocgvSAMwEMBjWlDgAeACqgAvKADeAXwB8stqFWgAFLxjoAXKABKeXgBMkZBAE8okXhZHoCkctAUAaUPwDuxxnodOKAEo9YVhxBQBuNhU1XgQSXnQRAGkARlA8AA9OMmNMGgskblAxd2SAJgzsvFzMf2cFdXQiJEgCADlefD0092QKTu7QCtAAHwMjU3MrSBs7CoVgiBgwiQAyWVAAbQLQcmHygF09MS20w9BFKNY1UDiEpLSqnLzQAqKSssqsl7rHBqaLTagzwPXKfTM0BBPXS40MJjMlmsthSqUWIRW4lAGxk212+wqxxKZ1SFyuMVU90SgNaHS6oKw-woYwmCOmyLs9QobkQkOhjIClDhk0RMzm9iZLiWoXC11uVPQmniiTwuk2W2atP5XOgRJ1LPhUyRsxROqUcmlmLEkTYcmirDYIFARAIBAADroQA4BKgkLAuNxkJ4AHT8XDAXjAACsAAYAMwAdij5QAHAA2YDlOMAThTMfKMbYBAsbtoAFUyCQzGIkABJMicSDoPD8AhVsgiMtKaQUjRl541V68MgWUCMDSoPRlwJSJSwJAkYygPRkPD+yAzn6DzDqdSTvZkbhcUC1meSOcL4wz8e15egVfr65Fku0ACaWmg6AAQgBXEgIYwuBEcAB1qZY4G7DQLAxOAzyUcAn1YYtS1AAB9aBCHfGBf3-QCmzEF8K3bYDQNeLDPxwgCgOHCwFC2Q5IJkXszgPN48EKYpwCJcAzguLcwPI78-yoyBgMxcgj0gEoFCUccJBXNdj1tLYAFFMn4BAf0AkR3k49xdO2BjDkQ5DaFQzwSGIAB5N02zMdBDHQH8EAIEj+LIj8hNw6iRzohipF7QTKLwsTRCI6s6wbLhm1bYj0Mwj9guigjS3CjtwBkmT7SyN1aVAbgfzIWKzFACzrNs9skhA9zMCC4SQpovzGmDFrPJCJZzMsogbLssgHNVZzXIy64crygqit60qup6yr1Ba4M2tAOrvNExr6KWZaRJERrlBuNRIEIH9IDIe9nIQO5MBoiJQCdMQrIAESs217VulSAGUxFrdoAHEdBesBNrw9A2DDPqCAgGMpA0D8YLCXFMj8SVLkWWc7hga5QYcCB0mkTQYFhkRcW4Eh-T0KNkbgtHoAx+zwfASpcZh8C4b2PIVx-HAACMuHoinUY-RDMfBgANKGyu6ir7PUcAY3ccBUjlhWIHKQJridIXQGFvRAaAmUmNYJ1bgRgVnDVsA5GxXbDbUYnSdAKMzcuS39et1RFzVMgOe5yB6MdxQFDYIA)

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/2398020
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;

type YargsBuilder<A extends Argv> = (y: Argv) => A;

type _getYargBuildersTypeUnion<A extends YargsBuilder<any>[]> = {
    [K in keyof A]: A[K] extends YargsBuilder<Argv<infer T>> ? T : never 
}[Exclude<keyof A, keyof []>];

type _withOptionsResult<A extends YargsBuilder<any>[]> =
    YargsBuilder<Argv<UnionToIntersection<_getYargBuildersTypeUnion<A>>>>

export function withOptions<A extends YargsBuilder<any>[]>(...args: A): _withOptionsResult<A>;
export function withOptions(...args: YargsBuilder<any>[]): YargsBuilder<any> {
    return null as any; // TODO
}
```

Test usage:

```
// YargsBuilders
const A0 = (arg: Argv<{ x: string }>) => arg;
const A1 = (arg: Argv<{ five: 5 }>) => arg;
const A2 = (arg: Argv<{ ids: number[] }>) => arg;

const X = withOptions(A0, A1, A1, A2);
// const X: YargsBuilder<Argv<{
//     x: string;
// } & {
//     five: 5;
// } & {
//     ids: number[];
// }>>
```

Comment: Wow... looks like I got some more typing magic to learn... This works exactly like I wanted 

Answer (score 1):

Why not pass all options as a configuration object?

Different languages support different tools for providing optional arguments, and while builders may be your only option in some other languages, configuration object is more idiomatic approach in JS, and yargs supports this it as well:

[.options(key, [opt])](https://yargs.js.org/docs/#api-reference-optionskey-opt)

> Optionally .options() can take an object that maps keys to opt parameters.
>
> ```
> var argv = require('yargs')
>    .options({
>      'f': {
>        alias: 'file',
>        demandOption: true,
>        default: '/etc/passwd',
>        describe: 'x marks the spot',
>        type: 'string'
>      }
>    })
>    .argv
> ;
> ```

So, in your case, it becomes sth like:

```
yargs.options({
  'foo': {
    type: 'string'
   },
   'bar': {
     type: 'string'
   },
   'baz': {
     type: 'string'
   },
})
```

You can extract some options to constants:

```
const fooOption = {
  'foo': {
      type: 'string'
  }
} as const;

const barOption = {
  'bar': {
      type: 'string'
  }
} as const;

const bazOption = {
  'baz': {
      type: 'string'
  }
} as const;

yargs.options({
    ...fooOption,
    ...barOption,
    ...bazOption
});
```

Comment: You're right in switching to the config object makes more sense, I forgot about the fact that yargs provides that too.

I'm still going to accept @Mingwei Samuel's answer, since my question was more about the typing intricacies and I think that's what people are going to look for coming here based on my question title.

Comment: @DeX3 fair enough